# Image loading (content Boxes) on Website?

Tags: image, loading

I have 12 images that make up the main content boxes on my website.  The problem is they are being loaded towards the bottom of my website according to firebug.

http://www.steelheadstalkers.com/videos_steelhead-salmon-trout_fishing.htm

I would like the 12 images that make up my content boxes (box1.png,box1-0.png,box1-1.png,box1-2.png,box1-3.png,box1-4.png,box1-5.png,box1-6.png,box1-7.png,box1-8.png,box1-l.png,box1-r.png) to load just after my nivo-slider.  Right now most of these images load towards the bottom of my website and it gives the appearance that my website takes longer to load than it should.  I would rather the content boxes load first then the content inside them.  Right now a lot of the images in the content boxes load before the actual boxes.  Let me know how I can get those content box images to load sooner?  I use JS, JQuery and CSS.  Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it.  Looks like the rounded box JS file had the load event triggered.  I changed it to DOMContentLoaded to fix the loading issue.  Work like a charm!